# Testing Observables in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test the setTimer function in Angular 4. My code looks like this:

```
setTimer(timeCounter?: number, initialDelay?: number): Observable<number> {
    return Observable.timer((isNumber(initialDelay) ? initialDelay * 1000 : DEFAULT_INITIAL_DELAY), DEFAULT_TIME_PERIOD)
      .map(i => isNumber(timeCounter) ? timeCounter - i : DEFAULT_TIME_COUNTER - i)
      .take(isNumber(timeCounter) ? timeCounter + 1 : DEFAULT_TIME_COUNTER + 1);
  }
```

So far I have tried:

```
it('should set timer and return time value', () => {
    timerService.setTimer(15, 0).subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
    });
  });
```

I'd like my test to be more consistent and check the values with jasmine.clock().tick() if possible...

Comment: Have you looked into [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync)? That's the Angular way to control time.

Comment: It doesn't work for observables...